# Oracle - For loop output issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this function in oracle which is supposed to get a comma separated list of numbers as input and iterate on each number and pass it to another function and then pipe the output.

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNC1(num_list varchar2,separator varchar2) RETURN typeAs PIPELINED 
as 
begin
FOR nums in (select regexp_substr(num_list,'[^'||separator||']+', 1, level) num from dual
  connect by regexp_substr(num_list, '[^'||separator||']+', 1, level) is not null)
loop
PIPE ROW(typeA(NVL(nums.num,0) ,NVL(FUNC2(nums.num),0)));
end loop;
end;
```

Noting that :

```
create or replace TYPE typeA AS OBJECT (num varchar2(20),val varchar2(20))
create or replace TYPE typeAs AS TABLE OF typeA;
```

the function works correctly in case all the numbers in the list will return an output other than null when passed to FUNC2. But if a number returns null when passed to FUNC2 , all followed numbers in the list are not shown in the output of FUNC1.

Edit: Results:

```
select * from table(FUNC1('1111,4333,121212',',')) :
output:
-----------------
1111 | val1
```

the other two numbers are not shown in the output as FUNC2('4333') is null , knowing that FUNC2('121212') has value.
while :

```
select * from table(FUNC1('1111,2222,121212',',')) :
output:
-----------------
1111     | val1
2222     | val2
121212   | val3
```

Comment: Show us the query that you use to call the `TABLE` function, the arguments that you passed and what output you are seeing in tabular form.Also, show part of `func2` if it'srelevant to your explanation

Comment: select * from table(FUNC1('1111,4333,121212',',')) :
>output:
>-----------------
>1111 | val1

the other two numbers are not shown in the output as FUNC2('4333') is null , knowing that FUNC2('121212') has value.
while :
select * from table(FUNC1('1111,2222,121212',',')) :
>output:
>-----------------
>1111     | val1
>2222    | val2
>121212| val3

Comment: @Kaushik I edited the question

Comment: Works fine for me. Please check  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0179e9fe43131c0768bc0c6201e9d147 There's some information that is missing in your question.

Comment: It looks like your `func2` is probably throwing a no-data-found exception, rather than returning null?

Comment: @Alex yes that was the problem. Issue is fixed after adding the Exception handling. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see that effect if `func2` is throwing a `no_data_found` exception, rather than returning null, for the input value 4333. That probably makes sense if that function is looking up the value from another table.

Because your call to `func1` is in a SQL context that exception is silently fatal, and execution bails when it's encountered, without any indication of what is wring. If you called `func1` from a PL/SQL context you would see the exception.

As a demo with a dummy `func2`:

```
create or replace function func2(p_num number) return varchar2 as
begin
  if p_num = 4333 then
    raise no_data_found;
  end if;

  return case p_num
    when 1111 then 'val1'
    when 2222 then 'val2'
    when 121212 then 'val3'
    else null
  end;
end func2;
/
```

and your original function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNC1(num_list varchar2,separator varchar2) RETURN typeAs PIPELINED 
as
  l_val varchar2(20);
begin
  FOR nums in (select regexp_substr(num_list,'[^'||separator||']+', 1, level) num from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(num_list, '[^'||separator||']+', 1, level) is not null)
  loop
    PIPE ROW(typeA(NVL(nums.num,0) ,NVL(FUNC2(nums.num),0)));
  end loop;
end;
/

select * from table(FUNC1('1111,4333,121212',','));

NUM                  VAL                 
-------------------- --------------------
1111                 val1                

select * from table(FUNC1('1111,2222,121212',','));

NUM                  VAL                 
-------------------- --------------------
1111                 val1                
2222                 val2                
121212               val3
```

You could change `func1` to call the function explicitly and handle the exception:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNC1(num_list varchar2,separator varchar2) RETURN typeAs PIPELINED 
as
  l_val varchar2(20);
begin
  FOR nums in (select regexp_substr(num_list,'[^'||separator||']+', 1, level) num from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(num_list, '[^'||separator||']+', 1, level) is not null)
  loop
    begin
      l_val := FUNC2(nums.num);
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        l_val := null;
    end;
    PIPE ROW(typeA(NVL(nums.num,0) ,NVL(l_val,0)));
  end loop;
end;
/

select * from table(FUNC1('1111,4333,121212',','));

NUM                  VAL                 
-------------------- --------------------
1111                 val1                
4333                 0                   
121212               val3                

select * from table(FUNC1('1111,2222,121212',','));

NUM                  VAL                 
-------------------- --------------------
1111                 val1                
2222                 val2                
121212               val3
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=91a819d2c27213b786c49ed0331d3b58).

Or you could change `func2` so it catches the exception and returns null, or changes its query so it can't get the exception in the first place. Whether that is appropriate is up to you - it may be used in other places where the exception needs to be propagated...

(Incidentally, as `func2` returns a string, the `nvl()` for that should really use a string too - even if that is `0`, as it is implicitly converted to now.)